Nested ViewModel with a Custom Data Annotation validation Not Working
I have created a custom data annotation to check if a value entered is equal to zero.  And it works when used on a parent view model.  However if I add it to a property in a nested view model, it does not work.  I'm confused why this is the case as [Required] works in the nested view model.
The parent view model:
public class ParentViewModel 
{
    public string ParentId { get; set; }

    public string ParentName { get; set; }

    public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel1 { get; set; }

}

The nested view model:
public class ChildViewModel 
{
    [NotEqualToZero(ErrorMessage = "Value Can Not Be Zero.")]
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Value 1")]
    public decimal ChildProperty1 { get; set; }
}

The Required validation works and if the textbox is empty, the error message will display.  However, when the value 0 is entered, the validation does not work.  Is there something I'm missing or not understanding?
